# Optimizing JOINs : comparison with indexed tables

Tags: join, left-join, inner-join, sqlperformance

Let's say we have a time consuming query described below :

```
(SELECT ...
FROM ...) AS FOO
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ...
    FROM ...) AS BAR
ON FOO.BarID = BAR.ID
```

Let's suppose that

```
(SELECT ...
FROM ...) AS FOO
```

Returns *many* rows (let's say 10 M). Every single row has to be joined with data in BAR.

Now let's say we insert the result of

```
    SELECT ...
    FROM ...) AS BAR
```

In a table, and add the ad hoc index(es) to it.

**My question** :

How would the performance of the "JOIN" with a *live* query differ from the performance of the "JOIN" to a table containing the result of the previous *live* query, to which ad hoc indexes would have been added ?

Another way to put it :

If a JOIN is slow, would there be any gain in actually storing and indexing the table to which we JOIN to ?

Comment: That could depend on the size of the table you wish to store, and the indexes, as creating such a table, inserting new rows into that table and then creting indexes on that table could be time consuming in itself...

Comment: @astander: please note that the question is actually about the "select" (inserts become slower with indexes, but that is not the focus here :) ).

Comment: @astander: the fact of gaining or losing performance during the select would IMHO NOT depend on the size of the table to store. We are talking about relative performance for solution A vs solution B. Not about absolute performance vs table size.

Comment: That specific measurement does not seem correct then, you need to take the full query execution time into account to be able to compare the 2 options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is 'Maybe'.

It depends on the statistics of the data in question. The only way you'll find out for sure is to actually load the first query into a temp table, stick a relevant index on it, then run the second part of the query.

I can tell you if speed is what you want, if it's possible for you load the results of your first query permanently into a table then of course your query is going to be quicker.

If you want it to be even faster, depending on which DBMS you are using you could consider creating an index which crosses both tables - if you're using SQL Server they're called 'Indexed Views' or you can also look up 'Reified indexes' for other systems.

Finally, if you want the ultimate in speed, consider denormalising your data and eliminating the join that is occurring on the fly - basically you move the pre-processing (the join) offline at the cost of storage space and data consistency (your live table will be a little behind depending on how frequently you run your updates).

I hope this helps.